# Nopcommerce payment Method friendly name returned to its default value after build the solution

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

I have a a project with nopCommerce 3.9, when logging to the admin portal and change the payment method friendly name from Configuration > payment > payment method.

Then clicking edit to change the friendly name of (Check / Money Order) it changed successfully but after rebuild the nopCommerce project the Friendly Name returned to its default value again (Check/Money Order)

How can I prevent it from returning to its default value after rebuild ??

Comment: Clear the cache!

Comment: yes, I already did this but the problem still exist

Comment: Does this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately ,No

Comment: Would you like to resolve it? then I'll take a look

Comment: thanks Div , if you could solve this , it will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is really interesting question, and you'll learn a lot after debugging the code. First of all, let's understand the how nopCommerce loading the plugins.

**Problem:**

When you build any plugin, it will generate DLLs and static files inside `Presentation > Nop.Web > Plugins` folder, and that folder being used through out the app.

[image]

Now when you change the `FrindlyName` from admin side, it'll update *Description.txt* file inside `Nop.Web > Plugins > Payment.CheckMoneyOrder`.

[image]

However, your main plugin code located at `Root > Plugins > Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder` which also contains *Description.txt* file, and that would be actual one, as you haven't modified it yet.

```
Group: Payment methods
FriendlyName: Check / Money Order
SystemName: Payments.CheckMoneyOrder
Version: 1.21
SupportedVersions: 3.90
Author: nopCommerce team
DisplayOrder: 1
FileName: Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.dll
Description: This plugin enables check and money order payments
```

So, when you build the solution, it will override the description file that you've modified previously. And that is why you facing this issue after build the project.

**Solution:** 
Change property "Copy to Output Directory" of description file to "do not copy".

[image]

Comment: @miladshafik If this solved your issue, please accept it as an answer.